# JavaScript Prototypal Inheritance: Why does call to getter/setter of child affect parent?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal

Please see the fiddle/code below:
http://jsfiddle.net/kmiklas/3YdTA/4/

Questions:

- Why does a call to the setter function of a child--in the example, the call to `Object.create(99)`--change the setting of the parent? Note how, although we've invoked this function in the context of **orange**, it's also changing the value for **red**.
- More importantly, how can inherited getter/setter functions be applied to the child, and not the parent?
- What am I missing here?

---

```
var Square = function () {
    var side;
    this.setSide = function(s) {
        side = s
    }
    this.getSide = function() {
        return side;
    }
}
var red = new Square();
var orange = Object.create(red);
red.setSide(100);
var $container = $('#container');
$container.append('orange.getSide(): ' + orange.getSide() + '<br>');
$container.append('red.getSide(): ' + red.getSide() + '</br><br>');
$container.append('<i>Now we call orange.setSide(99)...</i><br></br>');
orange.setSide(99);
$container.append('orange.getSide(): ' + orange.getSide() + ' <i>...as expected.<br></i>');
$container.append('red.getSide(): ' + red.getSide() + '!? <i>Why does the call to orange.setSide(99) affect the side length of the parent?</i></br>');
```

Comment: I don't understand what `Object.create(99)`, `orange` and `red` have to do with the code you posted. ...and there's no inheritance in that code.

Comment: You have to look at the fiddle... Did you vote this as off-topic? It is not; please remove on-hold status.

Comment: You need to put all relevant information needed to reproduce the issue directly in your question. I didn't vote it off-topic. A moderator did.

Comment: ok... added in the rest of the code needed to answer the question.

Comment: Just so you're clear on what prototypal inheritance is, it's really just a chain of objects used for looking up properties. In your example, the chain goes `orange -> red -> Square.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null`. So when you ask `orange` for a property, if it doesn't have it, it goes to `red`, and so on until it finds it or fails. So in your case, the property you're looking for is the `setSide` method. Because `orange` has no such method, it looks for it on `red` and finds it. Therefore it returns the `side` variable that was created in the `Square` constructor.

Comment: Yes! Helpful description... but I am calling `setSide()` in the context of `orange`; e.g., `orange.setSide(99)`. Why is this applied to `red`? Why does this not set the side length for the `orange` object?

Comment: It's because `side` is a local variable in the `Square` constructor, and not a property on any object. The only access to that variable is via the two methods that you placed on the `red` object. To make it more typical prototypal inheritance, but both methods on `Square.prototype`, get rid of the `var side`, and have the methods do `this.side = s;` in the setter, and `return this.side;` in the getter. Variables and properties are entirely separate things in JavaScript.

Comment: Ok. Only problem is that I was trying to keep side "private" by creating it as a local variable in the constructor. If I use `this.side = s;`, then `side` is now public, correct?

Comment: Correct. If you want it to be private, then it's not going to be accessible anywhere except via those methods. No matter how those methods are invoked, they'll always operate on the `var side;` created in that invocation of `Square`. Even if you do `var set = red.setSide; var get = red.getSide; set(123); get(); // 123;`, you're still manipulating the same variable.

Comment: ...if you do `Square.call(orange);`, this will invoke `Square` with the `orange` object as the `this` value. Because `Square` is being invoked, it's creating a new variable scope with its own `side` and `get/setSide` methods which are put on `this` (orange).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`The Object.create() method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.`

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

```
 var orange = Object.create(red);
```

You are not cloning the object this way, you are creating a new ref to it so any changes you mad to the original object will affect the all the copies to this object

```
var x = {name:"foo",phone:"bar"};
var y = Object.create(x);

x.u = "123";

console.log(y);//{name: "foo", phone: "bar", u: "123"} 
console.log(x);//{name: "foo", phone: "bar", u: "123"}
```

object are copied by `Ref` in javaScript

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/q8Tvq/)

see this on [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Very nice... Thank you!